# how to properly identify specific value to parse using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

Dear Collective Wisdom

I'm struggling trying to use rvest to parse a table from https://www.1944.pl/powstancze-biogramy,ord,nazwisko,0,strona,1.html

I need to loop through all nodes of the table and extract its values one by one. Then iterate to next page and repeat.

I intend to read the table values separately, because I need to add a variant loop in the code - for each row, if value in the "Data urodzenia" column equals "-" then the program should enter the  webpage corresponding to that row and extract some other value (tagged "Rocznik") instead.

For now, I'm having trouble with forcing the rvest to read values from the table. I think I don't quite follow the idea of html selectors... I'm able to read the entire table (per page) using the (".museumTableRow") tag in the following function:

```
library(rvest) 
library(tidyverse)

page <- read_html("https://www.1944.pl/powstancze-biogramy,ord,nazwisko,0,strona,1.html")
getPage <- function(html){
  html %>% 
    html_nodes(".museumTableRow") %>%      
    html_text() %>% 
    str_trim() %>%                       
    unlist()                             
}

Append_page <- getPage(page)
```

...but as I try to use selectors for specific cells of the table, I get an empty ("character(0)") response. I was trying to find relevant tags by inspecting the page manually and by using the selectorgadget plugin as suggested by the library creators. These seem odd (to me), ex. for the first name in the "Nazwisko" column the selectorgadget suggests:

".footable-even:nth-child(1) .footable-first-column .museumTableRow"

so I was also trying to play with them, but I with no success. I guess I don't fully understand how it works. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to force rvest to read this table cell by cell and append values from subsequent cells to a data.table.

I hope this is specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(glue)
page <- read_html("https://www.1944.pl/powstancze-biogramy,ord,nazwisko,0,strona,1.html")
dat <- page %>% html_elements(css="tbody tr")  
txt <- dat %>% html_text()
hrefs <- dat %>% html_element("a") %>% html_attr("href")
s <- lapply(1:length(txt), function(i)trimws(strsplit(txt[i], split="\\n")[[1]]))
out_txt <- t(sapply(s, function(x)x[which(x != "")]))
stem <- "https://www.1944.pl"
for(i in 1:nrow(out_txt)){
  if(out_txt[i,6] == "-"){
    u <- paste0(stem, hrefs[i])
    h <- read_html(u)
    btxt <- h %>% html_elements(css="div.biogram--info div.tag") %>% html_text()
    ind <- grep("Rocznik", btxt)
    if(length(ind) > 0){
      btxt2 <-   h %>% html_elements(css=glue("div.biogram--info div.info")) %>% html_text()
      out_txt[i,6] <- btxt2[ind]
    }else{
      out_txt[i,6] <- NA_character_
    }
  }
}
head(out_txt)
#             [,1]          [,2]         [,3]      [,4]            [,5]                [,6]         [,7]        
# [1,] "Abajew"      "Aleksander" "-"       "-"             "-"                 "1916-06-06" "-"         
# [2,] "Abakanowicz" "Piotr"      "-"       "-"             "\"Grey\""          "1890-06-21" "1948-06-01"
# [3,] "Abakanowicz" "Maria"      "-"       "-"             "\"Lena\""          "1901"       "-"         
# [4,] "Abczyńska"   "Alicja"     "Henryka" "sanitariuszka" "\"Ciocia Stasia\"" "1900-02-09" "1989-04-26"
# [5,] "Abczyńska"   "Janina"     "-"       "pielęgniarka"  "\"Julia\""         "1883-06-15" "1944-08-30"
# [6,] "Abczyński"   "Stanisław"  "-"       "-"             "\"Stefan\""        NA           "-"
```

In the code above, it grabs the data and the href for the first `<a>` tag in the row.  It then goes to that reference if the sixth column of the ith row is `"-"`.  If there is an entry labelled `"Rocznik"`, it grabs the year if it exists, otherwise it replaces the entry with a missing value.

---

#### Edit: Details about CSS selectors

I'll assume that everything up until the `stem <- "https://www.1944.pl"` part is pretty straightforward as it more or less follows the path you were already on.  So, let's dig into the `for` loop and how those things work.  As you noted, originally the third row had a `"-"` as its entry in the sixth column and this should trigger another lookup.  So, that means the third href should be followed:

```
hrefs[3]
# [1] "/powstancze-biogramy/maria-abakanowicz,845.html"
```

To do that, we can paste this onto the `stem` defined earlier to make a valid URL, which we read into `h`.  If you visit that URL in your browser, you see this:

[image]

You want to be able to identify the number associated with "Rocznik".  If you right-click on the word "Rocznik" and choose "inspect", you'll see this:

[image]

You'll notice that all of the entries are in a `<div>` with class `"biogram--info"`.  Further, the heading for each entry is in a `<div>` with class `"tag"`.  I edited the answer above to make the result a bit cleaner by using the `"tag"` div as well.  The results of `btxt` look as follows:

```
btxt <- h %>% 
  html_elements(css="div.biogram--info div.tag") %>% 
  html_text()
btxt
# [1] "Pseudonim:"                      
# [2] "Data urodzenia:"                 
# [3] "Data śmierci:"                   
# [4] "Funkcja:"                        
# [5] "Rocznik:"                        
# [6] "Stopień:"                        
# [7] "Pseudonimy:"                     
# [8] "Udział w konspiracji 1939-1944:" 
# [9] "Oddział:"                        
# [10] "Szlak bojowy:"                   
# [11] "Miejsce (okoliczności) śmierci :"
# [12] "Uwagi:"                          
# [13] "Publikacje :"
```

Then, you can figure out which one is "Rocznik" - in this case, the fifth one.  In the original answer (which I've edited to make a bit cleaner), I had

```
btxt2 <-   h %>% 
  html_elements(css=glue("div.biogram--info:nth-child({ind-1})")) %>%   
  html_text()
```

First, the meachanics - the `glue()` function is like `paste()` or `paste0()`, but sometimes a bit clearer in what it's doing.  In the statement above:

```
glue("div.biogram--info:nth-child({ind-1})")
```

would be equivalent to either of these:

```
paste0("div.biogram--info:nth-child(", ind-1, ")")
paste("div.biogram--info:nth-child(", ind-1, ")", sep="")
```

In `glue()`, anything that shows up within the braces `{}` gets evaluated in R and the result is then placed in the text.  From the code above `ind` identifies the value `<div>` associated with "Rocznik", but when we look at the thildren of `div.biogram--info`, we see that some of the children have multiple entries.  It's the fourth child `ind-1` that holds the "Rocznik" entry.

```
h %>% 
  html_elements(css="div.biogram--info:nth-child(1)") %>% 
  html_text()
# [1] "\n                        Pseudonim:\n                        \"Lena\"\n                    "                      
# [2] "\n                                Data urodzenia:\n                                -\n                            "
# [3] "\n                                Data śmierci:\n                                -\n                            "  

h %>% 
  html_elements(css="div.biogram--info:nth-child(2)") %>% 
  html_text()
# character(0)

h %>% 
  html_elements(css="div.biogram--info:nth-child(3)") %>% 
  html_text()
# [1] "\n                        Funkcja:\n                        -\n                    "

h %>% 
  html_elements(css="div.biogram--info:nth-child(4)") %>% 
  html_text()
# [1] "\n                                Rocznik:\n                                1901\n                            "
```

Then the code just extracts whatever sequential digits it finds.   I've edited the answer above to something that is probably a bit more robust.  If you look back at the picture of the html source, you'll see that for each `"biogram--info"` div, there is a `"tag"` class div that holds the heading and an `"info"` class div that holds the value associated with that heading.  Using the following code, you can retrieve all of the `"info"` entries that correspond with each `"tag"` entry:

```
btxt2 <- h %>% 
  html_elements(css=glue("div.biogram--info div.info")) %>% 
  html_text()
btxt2
# [1] "\"Lena\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# [2] "-"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# [3] "-"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# [4] "-"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# [5] "1901"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# [6] "starszy strzelec"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# [7] "\"Lenarska\", \"Lena\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# [8] "Narodowe Siły Zbrojne - Okręg I A Warszawa-Miasto"                                                                                                                                                                                                
# [9] "Armia Krajowa - Grupa \"Północ\" - zgrupowanie \"Sienkiewicz\" - następnie odcinek bojowy \"Kuba\" - \"Sosna\" - kompania P-20, następnie w 1. batalionie szturmowym KB \"Nałęcz\" . W Śródmieściu w batalionie KB \"Sokół\"  - patrol sanitarny."
# [10] "Stare Miasto - kanały - Śródmieście Północ"                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# [11] " Poległa na ul. Kopernika (VIII-IX 1944). Inne wersja - zmarła 1992-10-10\n"                                                                                                                                                                      
# [12] "Inny spotykany przydział  - Narodowe Siły Zbrojne - Grupa \"Topór\""                                                                                                                                                                              
# [13] "Wielka Ilustrowana Encyklopedia Powstania Warszawskiego Suplement, Warszawa, 2009"
```

To get the value associated with "Rocznik", you can take the `ind` entry of `btxt2` as is now done in the answer above.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thank you @DaveArmstrong. This is great. The only thing that confuses me how can I extend it to account for instances where there is "-" in column 6. In such cases, the script should find the webpage with detailed information for a given record, find a tag named "Rocznik" and replace the "-" in column 6 with the value under that tag.  Ex. consider row 3. Here, there is no date in column 6, so the script should find in the table code the url of that record (powstancze-biogramy/maria-abakanowicz,845.html) and then replace "-" with value of "Rocznik" under that url (1901)

Comment: (cont.) The necessity to account for such a situation is the reason why I was looking for solutions enabling me to read the table cell by cell rather than page by page, so that I could include an if statement in the case of column 6, like "if, for row x, this cell == "-" use record url and extract "Rocznik" value from that url instead of "-".

Comment: @Jan I edited my response to answer your question.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was after. Now I only have to study the details  - as I see, I have a lot to learn about regular expressions etc. Anyway, thanks again. This is awesome

Comment: @Jan I added some detail about how I got to where I got.  In the process, I identified a better way of identifying the appropriate entries and updated the original answer, though I also explained the original answer, too.

Comment: Sooo cool... Man thank you. Now I get it all. I wouldn't be able to comprehend it without your help, not so fast at least.  I learned a lot.